# Umbraco 5 keeps showing Login Expired on Administrator Panel

Tags: authentication, umbraco, umbraco5

On administration panel, Jupiter regularly takes off a "Login Expired" box asking to login again.

- I am using a IIS7 hosting service
- I am using SQL Server 2008 R2
- I checked the full trust capability on web.config adding *trust level="full"* (this is need on mi hosting)
- I manually add ASP.NET WebPages assemblies to */bin*  directory (except *System.Web.WebPages.Administration.dll* because it conflicts with Nuget assembly in Umbraco)

I checked the same site on IIS 7.5 through publishing on other hosting provider and this was solved but still I need solve this.

The admin panel is operating but It constatly needs relogin.
The log seems to show all working fine.

Anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the dates on your server, versus your workstation. They need to match, its a common problem, that catches a lot of people.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked it that was good. I think that the probem is the RAM allocated. WinHost Basic Plan (the contracted hosting) has the limit on 100MB. I made a little test on IISExpress and I get a ~150MB usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can also be caused when your app pool recycles. I've noticed that the popup seems to appear after the app pool has been recyled or restarted on the server.